# Table goes off the bottom of the page

Tags: tables

Is there a way to move a table to the next page if it doesn't fit on the current page?

Currently my table goes off the page because it is too high - I'd like it to realise it's too high and therefore move it to the next page.

An example of the generated pdf: [example](http://picosoft.co.uk/tableOffBottom.pdf)

An example of the source code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newenvironment{Table}
  {\par\bigskip\noindent\minipage{\columnwidth}\centering}
  {\endminipage\par\bigskip}

\newenvironment{SCTable}
  {\vspace{-1em}\begin{Table}\begin{tabular}{m{1.4cm} m{2.2cm} m{1.2cm} m{1.2cm} m{1cm}}\hline\\[-1.5ex]}
  {\end{tabular}\end{Table}}



\begin{document}  


\newpage                                            
\begin{table}                                           
\begin{tabular}{rlrlrlrl}                                           
\textbf{Role:}  & DVR   & \textbf{Diagram:} & STP: IF 233: Su   & \textbf{Schedule Applies:}    &  Sun, 28/06/15    & \textbf{Name:}    & \\
\end{tabular}                                           
\end{table}                                         

\begin{multicols}{2}                                            
\vspace{1em}                                            
\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{TAXI}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
    & Ilford Depot  &       & 06:00 &      \\           
        & Shenfield & 06:30 &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
PU  & 5W07  &       &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{5W07}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
G:72953 & Shenf MSdg    &       & 07:00 & \\            
        & Shenfield & 07:02 &       & 4\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2W07}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:1021  & Shenfield &       & 07:14 & EL/4\\            
G:81492 & Brentwood & 07:17 & 07:17\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Harold Wood   & 07:21\textonehalf & 07:22 & 3\\           
        & Gidea Park    & 07:25\textonehalf & 07:26 & EL/3\\            
        & Romford   & 07:28 & 07:28\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 07:32 & 07:32\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Goodmayes & 07:34 & 07:34\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Seven Kings   & 07:36 & 07:36\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Ilford    & 07:38\textonehalf & 07:39 & EL/3\\            
        & Manor Park    & 07:41 & 07:41\textonehalf & EL\\          
        & Forest Gate   & 07:43 & 07:44 & EL/1\\            
        & Maryland  & 07:45\textonehalf & 07:46 & 1\\           
        & Stratford & 07:47\textonehalf & 07:48\textonehalf & EL/5\\            
        & Liverpool St  & 07:56 &       & 16\\          
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2C10}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:0112  & Liverpool St  &       & 08:17 & EL/16\\           
G:86408 & Stratford & 08:23\textonehalf & 08:24\textonehalf & EL/8\\            
        & Forest Gate   & 08:26\textonehalf & 08:27 & EL/2\\            
        & Manor Park    & 08:28\textonehalf & 08:29 & EL\\          
        & Ilford    & 08:31\textonehalf & 08:32 & EL/4\\            
        & Seven Kings   & 08:34 & 08:34\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Goodmayes & 08:36 & 08:36\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 08:38 & 08:38\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Romford   & 08:42 & 08:42\textonehalf & 5\\           
        & Gidea Park    & 08:46 &       & 4\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
RELD    & by GP 205  at     & 08.46 &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
PNB &       &       &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
REL & GP 202  at    & 09.46 &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{5C14}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
G:87908 & Gidea Park    &       & 09:47 & 4\\           
        & Gid Pk MSdg   & 09:49 &       & \\            
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{5C25}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
G:03029 & Gid Pk MSdg   &       & 10:08 & \\            
        & Gidea Park    & 10:10 &       & 3\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2C25}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:1012  & Gidea Park    &       & 10:11 & EL/3\\            
G:11568 & Romford   & 10:13 & 10:13\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 10:17 & 10:17\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Goodmayes & 10:19 & 10:19\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Seven Kings   & 10:21 & 10:21\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Ilford    & 10:23\textonehalf & 10:24 & EL/3\\            
        & Manor Park    & 10:26 & 10:26\textonehalf & EL\\          
        & Forest Gate   & 10:28 & 10:29 & EL/1\\            
        & Stratford & 10:31\textonehalf & 10:32\textonehalf & EL/5\\            
        & Liverpool St  & 10:41 &       & 16\\          
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2W28}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:0122  & Liverpool St  &       & 11:05 & EL/16\\           
G:66705 & Stratford & 11:11\textonehalf & 11:12\textonehalf & EL/8\\            
        & Maryland  & 11:13\textonehalf & 11:14 & 2\\           
        & Forest Gate   & 11:15\textonehalf & 11:16 & EL/2\\            
        & Manor Park    & 11:17\textonehalf & 11:18 & EL\\          
        & Ilford    & 11:20\textonehalf & 11:21 & EL/4\\            
        & Seven Kings   & 11:23 & 11:23\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Goodmayes & 11:25 & 11:25\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 11:27 & 11:27\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Romford   & 11:31 & 11:31\textonehalf & 5\\           
        & Gidea Park    & 11:34\textonehalf & 11:35 & EL/4\\            
        & Harold Wood   & 11:37\textonehalf & 11:38 & 4\\           
        & Brentwood & 11:42 & 11:42\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Shenfield & 11:47 &       & 5\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{5W28}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
G:58166 & Shenfield &       & 11:49 & S2/5\\            
        & Shenf MSdg    & 11:52 &       & \\            
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{5W43}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
G:73315 & Shenf MSdg    &       & 12:05 & \\            
        & Shenfield & 12:08 &       & 4\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2W43}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:1021  & Shenfield &       & 12:14 & EL/4\\            
G:81854 & Brentwood & 12:17 & 12:17\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Harold Wood   & 12:21\textonehalf & 12:22 & 3\\           
        & Gidea Park    & 12:25\textonehalf & 12:26 & EL/3\\            
        & Romford   & 12:28 & 12:28\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 12:32 & 12:32\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Goodmayes & 12:34 & 12:34\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Seven Kings   & 12:36 & 12:36\textonehalf & 3\\           
        & Ilford    & 12:38\textonehalf & 12:39 & EL/3\\            
        & Manor Park    & 12:41 & 12:41\textonehalf & EL\\          
        & Forest Gate   & 12:43 & 12:44 & EL/1\\            
        & Maryland  & 12:45\textonehalf & 12:46 & 1\\           
        & Stratford & 12:47\textonehalf & 12:48\textonehalf & EL/5\\            
        & Liverpool St  & 12:57 &       & 17\\          
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{2C46}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
S:0112  & Liverpool St  &       & 13:17 & EL/17\\           
G:86770 & Stratford & 13:23\textonehalf & 13:24\textonehalf & EL/8\\            
        & Forest Gate   & 13:26\textonehalf & 13:27 & EL/2\\            
        & Manor Park    & 13:28\textonehalf & 13:29 & EL\\          
        & Ilford    & 13:31\textonehalf & 13:32 & EL/4\\            
        & Seven Kings   & 13:34 & 13:34\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Goodmayes & 13:36 & 13:36\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Chad. Heath   & 13:38 & 13:38\textonehalf & 4\\           
        & Romford   & 13:42 & 13:42\textonehalf & 5\\           
        & Gidea Park    & 13:46 &       & 4\\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
RELD    & by GP 205  at     & 13.46 &       &      \\           
\end{SCTable}                                           

\begin{SCTable}                                         
\textbf{PASS}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\         
    & Gidea Park    &       & 13:55 &      \\           
        & Seven Kings   & 14:05 &       &      \\           
    &   &   &   & \\            
\textbf{End of} & \textbf{Diagram}  &   &   & \\            
\end{SCTable}                                           
\end{multicols}                                         



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Normally, this gets done by default so there must be something in your code preventing it from happening. Can you post a small, compilable document here which reproduces the issue?

Comment: use `\raggedbottom` in the preamble or use package `longtable` with the environment of the same name.

Comment: I'll have a try with raggedbottom @Herbert. I thought longtable was for spanning multiple pages with the same table?

Comment: Out of interest: Are you aware that every line contains multiple spaces and tabs?

Comment: I see no strange behaviour compiling your code.

Comment: @James: if one table is too high yot need a pagebreak.

Comment: @Johannes_B I was aware about the tabs/spaces - I thought these would be ignored? It's strange it works for you, I'm compiling to a pdf with texworks, what are you using? PDF link added to the original question

Comment: @Herbert I'd like latex to work out when the page needs to be broken, is that an unfair expectation?

Comment: There is a bit more stretching in your pdf. Might be a version issue, there have been a few changes to pdftex over the years.

Comment: this code works just fine under tex live 2012; the only complaints are about a lot of `overfull \hbox (2.10693pt too wide)`.  so my guess is that it is a version problem where something changed between 2012 and now.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help. It sounds like downgrading is the only option, is that right? Any suggestions on a different way I could structure the document that wouldn't be so problematic?

Comment: I don't see the problem with TeX Live 2015, so I don't think the only solution can be downgrading. I can reproduce it with TeX Live 2014, though. I actually have a similar issue in a document of mine which works fine with current TL but looks a mess on OverLeaf or if I use TL 2014 on my own machine. But I don't have a solution :(. Other than upgrading.

Comment: @cfr Upgrading would be an option but I'm currently running 2015 - `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)`

Comment: All I can say is the problem disappears with current TL 2015 from upstream. Could be Debian's packaging has not caught the latest update of something. You could add `\listfiles` and post the results here to try to figure out what is different. Or you could install upstream's TL and remove Debian's.

Answer (score 1):

This is a not-nice hack and upgrading would be a better option. However, if you really need it to work and just cannot upgrade, the following *may* help. However, you will need to examine the output carefully in case of unwanted side-effects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newenvironment{SCTable}
{\centering\bigskip\begin{tabular}{m{1.4cm} m{2.2cm} m{1.2cm} m{1.2cm} m{1cm}}\hline\\[-1.5ex]}
  {\end{tabular}\vspace*{\fill}\par\mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]\bigskip}

\begin{document}

  \newpage
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{rlrlrlrl}
      \textbf{Role:}  & DVR   & \textbf{Diagram:} & STP: IF 233: Su   & \textbf{Schedule Applies:}    &  Sun, 28/06/15    & \textbf{Name:}    & \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \vspace{1em}
    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{TAXI}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      & Ilford Depot  &       & 06:00 &      \\
      & Shenfield & 06:30 &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      PU  & 5W07  &       &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{5W07}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      G:72953 & Shenf MSdg    &       & 07:00 & \\
      & Shenfield & 07:02 &       & 4\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2W07}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:1021  & Shenfield &       & 07:14 & EL/4\\
      G:81492 & Brentwood & 07:17 & 07:17\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Harold Wood   & 07:21\textonehalf & 07:22 & 3\\
      & Gidea Park    & 07:25\textonehalf & 07:26 & EL/3\\
      & Romford   & 07:28 & 07:28\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 07:32 & 07:32\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Goodmayes & 07:34 & 07:34\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Seven Kings   & 07:36 & 07:36\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Ilford    & 07:38\textonehalf & 07:39 & EL/3\\
      & Manor Park    & 07:41 & 07:41\textonehalf & EL\\
      & Forest Gate   & 07:43 & 07:44 & EL/1\\
      & Maryland  & 07:45\textonehalf & 07:46 & 1\\
      & Stratford & 07:47\textonehalf & 07:48\textonehalf & EL/5\\
      & Liverpool St  & 07:56 &       & 16\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2C10}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:0112  & Liverpool St  &       & 08:17 & EL/16\\
      G:86408 & Stratford & 08:23\textonehalf & 08:24\textonehalf & EL/8\\
      & Forest Gate   & 08:26\textonehalf & 08:27 & EL/2\\
      & Manor Park    & 08:28\textonehalf & 08:29 & EL\\
      & Ilford    & 08:31\textonehalf & 08:32 & EL/4\\
      & Seven Kings   & 08:34 & 08:34\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Goodmayes & 08:36 & 08:36\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 08:38 & 08:38\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Romford   & 08:42 & 08:42\textonehalf & 5\\
      & Gidea Park    & 08:46 &       & 4\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      RELD    & by GP 205  at     & 08.46 &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      PNB &       &       &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      REL & GP 202  at    & 09.46 &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{5C14}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      G:87908 & Gidea Park    &       & 09:47 & 4\\
      & Gid Pk MSdg   & 09:49 &       & \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{5C25}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      G:03029 & Gid Pk MSdg   &       & 10:08 & \\
      & Gidea Park    & 10:10 &       & 3\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2C25}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:1012  & Gidea Park    &       & 10:11 & EL/3\\
      G:11568 & Romford   & 10:13 & 10:13\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 10:17 & 10:17\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Goodmayes & 10:19 & 10:19\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Seven Kings   & 10:21 & 10:21\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Ilford    & 10:23\textonehalf & 10:24 & EL/3\\
      & Manor Park    & 10:26 & 10:26\textonehalf & EL\\
      & Forest Gate   & 10:28 & 10:29 & EL/1\\
      & Stratford & 10:31\textonehalf & 10:32\textonehalf & EL/5\\
      & Liverpool St  & 10:41 &       & 16\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2W28}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:0122  & Liverpool St  &       & 11:05 & EL/16\\
      G:66705 & Stratford & 11:11\textonehalf & 11:12\textonehalf & EL/8\\
      & Maryland  & 11:13\textonehalf & 11:14 & 2\\
      & Forest Gate   & 11:15\textonehalf & 11:16 & EL/2\\
      & Manor Park    & 11:17\textonehalf & 11:18 & EL\\
      & Ilford    & 11:20\textonehalf & 11:21 & EL/4\\
      & Seven Kings   & 11:23 & 11:23\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Goodmayes & 11:25 & 11:25\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 11:27 & 11:27\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Romford   & 11:31 & 11:31\textonehalf & 5\\
      & Gidea Park    & 11:34\textonehalf & 11:35 & EL/4\\
      & Harold Wood   & 11:37\textonehalf & 11:38 & 4\\
      & Brentwood & 11:42 & 11:42\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Shenfield & 11:47 &       & 5\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{5W28}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      G:58166 & Shenfield &       & 11:49 & S2/5\\
      & Shenf MSdg    & 11:52 &       & \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{5W43}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      G:73315 & Shenf MSdg    &       & 12:05 & \\
      & Shenfield & 12:08 &       & 4\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2W43}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:1021  & Shenfield &       & 12:14 & EL/4\\
      G:81854 & Brentwood & 12:17 & 12:17\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Harold Wood   & 12:21\textonehalf & 12:22 & 3\\
      & Gidea Park    & 12:25\textonehalf & 12:26 & EL/3\\
      & Romford   & 12:28 & 12:28\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 12:32 & 12:32\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Goodmayes & 12:34 & 12:34\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Seven Kings   & 12:36 & 12:36\textonehalf & 3\\
      & Ilford    & 12:38\textonehalf & 12:39 & EL/3\\
      & Manor Park    & 12:41 & 12:41\textonehalf & EL\\
      & Forest Gate   & 12:43 & 12:44 & EL/1\\
      & Maryland  & 12:45\textonehalf & 12:46 & 1\\
      & Stratford & 12:47\textonehalf & 12:48\textonehalf & EL/5\\
      & Liverpool St  & 12:57 &       & 17\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{2C46}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      S:0112  & Liverpool St  &       & 13:17 & EL/17\\
      G:86770 & Stratford & 13:23\textonehalf & 13:24\textonehalf & EL/8\\
      & Forest Gate   & 13:26\textonehalf & 13:27 & EL/2\\
      & Manor Park    & 13:28\textonehalf & 13:29 & EL\\
      & Ilford    & 13:31\textonehalf & 13:32 & EL/4\\
      & Seven Kings   & 13:34 & 13:34\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Goodmayes & 13:36 & 13:36\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Chad. Heath   & 13:38 & 13:38\textonehalf & 4\\
      & Romford   & 13:42 & 13:42\textonehalf & 5\\
      & Gidea Park    & 13:46 &       & 4\\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      RELD    & by GP 205  at     & 13.46 &       &      \\
    \end{SCTable}

    \begin{SCTable}
      \textbf{PASS}   & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Arr}  & \textbf{Dep}  & \textbf{Lne/Pf}\\
      & Gidea Park    &       & 13:55 &      \\
      & Seven Kings   & 14:05 &       &      \\
      &   &   &   & \\
      \textbf{End of} & \textbf{Diagram}  &   &   & \\
    \end{SCTable}

  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This is the output with TeX Live 2014:

[image: hack]

An updated TeX Live 2015 *does not need this hack*. The original code works perfectly in this case (apart from the numerous overfull `\hbox` warnings).